# pyOpenSSL and the WantReadError

Tags: python, ssl, pyopenssl

I have a socket server that I am trying to move over to SSL on python 2.5, but I've run into a snag with pyOpenSSL. I can't find any good tutorials on using it, so I'm operating largely on guesses.

Here is how my server sets up the socket:

```
ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
ctx.use_privatekey_file ("mykey.pem")
ctx.use_certificate_file("mycert.pem")
sock = SSL.Connection(ctx, socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM))
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
addr = ('', int(8081))
sock.bind(addr)
sock.listen(5)
```

Here is how it accepts clients:

```
sock.setblocking(0)
while True:
  if len(select([sock], [], [], 0.25)[0]):
    client_sock, client_addr = sock.accept()
    client = ClientGen(client_sock)
```

And here is how it sends/receives from the connected sockets:

```
while True:
  (r, w, e) = select.select([sock], [sock], [], 0.25)

  if len(r):
    bytes = sock.recv(1024)
  if len(w):
    n_bytes = sock.send(self.message)
```

It's compacted, but you get the general idea. The problem is, once the send/receive loop starts, it dies right away, before anything has been sent or received (that I can see anyway):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ClientGen.py", line 50, in networkLoop
    n_bytes = sock.send(self.message
WantReadError
```

The manual's description of the 'WantReadError' is very vague, saying it can come from just about anywhere. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes in order to send application bytes of an SSL connection, you need to be able to read more bytes from the connection first.  `WantReadError` is how this case is indicated.  The only thing you're doing wrong is that you're not handling the `WantReadError` and then waiting until `select` indicates that the socket is *readable* before you try calling `send` again.